# Convert seconds to HH:MM

Tags: r

I have a column with amount of seconds instead of the time due to an import flaw.

I managed to transform the seconds into xxH xxM xxS format by using the lubridate package.

`dt$column <- seconds_to_period(dt$column)`

But what I need is 14:30 instead of 14H 30M 00S. I tried the following but now I only have NA's in my time column:

```
myTime <- "14:11:49"
hms(myTime)
POSIXct_myTime <- parse_date_time(myTime,"hms")
format(POSIXct_myTime, format="%H:%M")
Dataset$Aanvangstijdstip <- format(POSIXct_myTime, format="%H:%M")

head(df$column) gives: [1] "17H 0M 0S"  "20H 0M 0S"  "9H 0M 0S"   "14H 30M 0S" "10H 15M 0S" "14H 30M 0S"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your Q and provide a [mcve]. As it is stated it is unclear what you are asking. Which package(s) are you using? If It's `lubridate` the call is `seconds_to_period()` not `seconds to period()`.

Comment: Try with `format(strptime(myTime, "%H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M")`

Comment: Does your input data include a date field as well? `POSIXct`is always a full date time. That's probably why you see `NA`. IMHO, it's easier to work with POSIXct than to handle dat and time of day in separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to follow allong these lines to convert the seconds field to a character string in format `HH:MM`:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# create sample data
dt <- data.table(seconds_of_day = 60 * 15 * seq(11, 77, 11))
# convert seconds to period
dt[, period := seconds_to_period(seconds_of_day)]
# convert period to time of day _as character string_ !
dt[, time_of_day := sprintf("%02i:%02i", hour(period), minute(period))]
dt
#   seconds_of_day     period time_of_day
#1:           9900  2H 45M 0S       02:45
#2:          19800  5H 30M 0S       05:30
#3:          29700  8H 15M 0S       08:15
#4:          39600  11H 0M 0S       11:00
#5:          49500 13H 45M 0S       13:45
#6:          59400 16H 30M 0S       16:30
#7:          69300 19H 15M 0S       19:15
```

Alternatively, the intermediate step of converting `seconds_of_day` to  `period` objects could be replaced by converting to class `POSIXct`. However, we do need a reference date where the seconds can be added to for this:

```
ref_date <- ymd("2017-01-01", tz = "UTC")
dt[, time_of_day2 := format(ref_date + seconds_of_day, "%H:%M")]
dt
#   seconds_of_day     period time_of_day time_of_day2
#1:           9900  2H 45M 0S       02:45        02:45
#2:          19800  5H 30M 0S       05:30        05:30
#3:          29700  8H 15M 0S       08:15        08:15
#4:          39600  11H 0M 0S       11:00        11:00
#5:          49500 13H 45M 0S       13:45        13:45
#6:          59400 16H 30M 0S       16:30        16:30
#7:          69300 19H 15M 0S       19:15        19:15
```

Note that the parameter `tz = "UTC"` to `ymd()` is essential to ensure the solution works independent of the local time zone.

Comment: Thanks the second solution is nice, is the ref date necessary for `format` function ? I dont inderstand why it's needed